# Counting contracted forms as one word

Tags: python

I'm making a word counter program in Python. I used the following regex:

```
match = re.findall(r'\w+',fetch)
```

At first, it seemed working fine. However, upon reading another post here, I came to realize that this regex code actually can't count contracted forms like "can't", "don't". I also want my program to count contracted forms as one word as Microsoft Word does so that my program can be full-fledged word counter. How I can do this?

Comment: "can't" = "can not", "don't" = "do not", so two words are pretty accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of focussing too much on contracted forms, etc. We can focus on *non-spaces* (i.e. `\S`), and thus use it as:

```
match = re.findall(r'\S+',fetch)
```

This would then produce:

```
>>> fetch = "I don't want to count contracted forms like don't and can't as two words."
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\S+', fetch)
['I', "don't", 'want', 'to', 'count', 'contracted', 'forms', 'like', "don't", 'and', "can't", 'as', 'two', 'words.']
```

Note that we also add the dot after words to dot. So we count sequences of non-spaces.

Comment: This will catch other punctuations like `'words.'`

Comment: @Tai: that is even in the answer. Yes, it does. The question is whether that is a problem.

Comment: True. I am not sure as well. It should depend on OP's problem.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actually, it would be a problem. My program is counting the word frequency. For example, what if the word "words" can be caught and "words." can't be because the latter has a dot in the end? That's what I'm concerned about.

Comment: @SüleymanYaman: In that case I think it would be more beneficial to convert `can't` into `can not`, etc. or use a stemmer like the Portman stemmer.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, You can use [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) with one or more space like this :

```
match = re.split('\s+', fetch)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This also count "can't"

```
len(fetch.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Add the needed punctuations in the bracket. Other answers potentially catch other punctuations like ".". It should depend on the problem to decide which would fit.

```
match = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z\']+',fetch)
fetch = "That's crazy. I'm not going to be like that. I just can't."

["That's",
 'crazy',
 "I'm",
 'not',
 'going',
 'to',
 'be',
 'like',
 'that',
 'I',
 'just',
 "can't"]
```